# What is the intuition behind this recursive function?

Tags: intuition, recursion, bit-strings

The problem that I'm working on is:

> How many binary strings (strings with only 0 or 1) of length 10 are there such that there are no 3 consecutive ones and no 2 consecutive zeros?

Let $a_n$ be the number of binary strings of length $n$ that satisfy the second condition (no 3 consecutive ones and no 2 consecutive zeros) and start with a $0$. Let $b_n$ be the number of binary strings of length $n$ that satisfy the second condition and start with a $1$. Let $c_n$ be the total number valid binary strings of length $n$. Let $a$ be a string that starts with $0$ and let $b$ be a string that starts with $1$.

$a = (0\ldots)$

The second digit in $a_n$ must be a $1$ because there cannot be $2$ consecutive zeros.

$a = 01\ldots$

If there is another zero, then we have started a binary string of length $n - 2$ that starts with a zero.

$a = 01(0\ldots)$

The number of such strings is $a_{n-2}$. If we have another $1$ instead of a $0$, then the next digit after the $1$ must be a $0$ because there cannot be three consecutive ones.

$a = 011(0\ldots)$

The number of such strings is $a_{n-3}$. Because we have considered all cases when the binary string starts with $0$, we know that $a_n = a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$.

Now, let's build a relationship for $b_n$. First, we note that $b = (1\ldots)$. If there is a zero after that, then a one must follow that zero because there cannot be $2$ consecutive zeros.

$b = 10(1\ldots)$

We have formed another binary string of length $n - 2$ that starts with 1. There are $b_{n-2}$ such strings. If we have a $1$ instead of a $0$, then the next digit must be a $0$ because there cannot be $3$ consecutive ones.

$b = 110\ldots$

The next digit must be a $1$ because there cannot be 2 consecutive zeros.

$b = 110(1\ldots)$

We formed another binary string of length $n - 3$ that starts with a $1$. There are $b_{n - 3}$ such strings. We have considered all cases that start with a $1$, so we know that $b_n = b_{n - 2} + b_{n - 3}$.

Notice that $a_n + b_n = c_n$. We add together $a_n = a_{n - 2} + a_{n - 3}$ and $b_n = b_{n - 2} + b_{n - 3}$ to get $(a_n + b_n) = (a_{n - 2} + b_{n - 2}) + (a_{n - 3} + b_{n - 3})$. This means that $c_n = c_{n - 2} + c_{n - 3}$.

That is such a simple recursive equation, but I don't have any intuitive understanding why the equation would be true.

Comment: Hmm, an unambiguous regular expression for the language would be $(\varepsilon|1|11)(01|011)^*(\varepsilon|0)$; therefore, the generating function for the sequence should be $(1+x+x^2) \cdot \frac{1}{1-(x^2+x^3)} \cdot (1+x)$; you can then see the recursion $c_n = c_{n-2} + c_{n-3}$ falling out from the denominator being $1-x^2-x^3$.

Comment: Technically $c_n=a_n+b_n-\delta_{n0}$, so $c_{n+3}=c_n+c_{n+1}+\delta_{n0}$ for $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relevant, intuitive interpretation of the [Padovan sequence](https://oeis.org/A000931), whose recurrence relation is

$\displaystyle P(n)=P(n-\color{red}2)+P(n-\color{red}3),$

corresponding with the condition that there ought be no $\color{red}2$ consecutive zeros and no $\color{red}3$ consecutive ones in your problem,

namely: $P(n)$ is the number of compositions of $(n + 2)$ in which each term is either $\color{red}2$ or $\color{red}3$.

For example, $P(6) = 4$, and there are $4$ ways to write $(6+2)=8$ as an ordered sum of $2$s and $3$s:

$8=2 + 2 + 2 + 2$
$8=2 + 3 + 3$
$8=3 + 2 + 3$
$8=3 + 3 + 2$

Nota bene that the above needs starting values
$P(0)=P(1)=P(2)=1$, which is different from OEIS' definition with
$P(0)=1$ and $P(1)=P(2)=0$

When offset by eight, OEIS' $P(n)$ is again giving the number of strings of length $(n-8)$ from a binary alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ with no more than one $0$ and no more than two $1$'s consecutively.